# Strip WebRTC RTCSessionDescription.sdp to minimum?

Tags: webrtc, sdp

I am trying to build a chat app between two browsers without a signal server with WebRTC. The manual offer-answer process is most difficult part of the task.

It occurred to me that most SDP data generated by `new RTCPeerConnection().createOffer()` as in `RTCSessionDescription.sdp` is redundant.

Reference: https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/

I tested, the `o=` line can be striped like `o=- 1 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1` and it works totally fine, the `a=candidate:` line contains FOUNDATION identifier and priority are completely useless, supposedly there's only one candidate in my case.

My question is, for the simple (and insecure) chat app between two browsers without ICE, can we strip down `a=ice-pwd:` line and `a=fingerprint:` line? The rest of SDP looks identical and can be just hard-coded into both peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question came up on WebRTCHacks before:
https://webrtchacks.com/the-minimum-viable-sdp/
There haven't been that many changes since 2015 so it should still apply.